# Eclipse: How to perform a task before eclipse view starts

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have only one view in my plugin. And before the view starts, I want to make sure my server has been started as the view will be started depending on server. Currently, I start my server in `Display thread` as `Display.getDefault().syncExec()`, while starting my plugin - `start(BundleContext context)`.

Sometimes, I see a deadlock between `bundleloader` and this thread. `Bundleloader` is waiting for my plugin to start, whereas my plugin start is waiting for the server to start because of `syncExec()` call.

How can I achieve this? Is there any way to perform a particular task before my view start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using E4 and your view extends `org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart`, there is an `init()`

```
void init(IViewSite site) throws PartInitException
```

which is called before `createPartControl(Composite parent)`.

Maybe that helps?

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid `Display.getDefault().syncExec()`; this call can block the UI - Eclipse will freeze without any indication why.

Instead, you should start a background thread / worker job. When the worker is done (your server has been started), you should send a signal to the view.

The view should initialize itself with "Starting server...". When the signal arrives, you can update the UI to display the actual content. That way, you don't have to block and the user will see why they don't see anything :-) You can also display error messages when you couldn't start the server, etc.